# PlayFramework sort of middleware

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play Framework for the first time.

Generally in Node.js (with Express) I did something like this:

*This code simply check if the request "wants" an html file, if so it send the index.html file, else it pass the request to the api routers, in order to answer with a json.*

```
   app.use('*', function(req,res, next){
        if(req.accepts('html')){
            var options = {
                root: __dirname + '/public/',
            };
            return res.sendFile('index.html', options);
        }else{
            next();
        }
    });
```

So for example if I ask an html page with any url, the server returns the index.html file, but if I ask a JSON (or any other stuff that is not an html), the server uses the other routes to answer the request.

Pratical example:

- request to /api/user -> the server handle as route "/api/user" with Controller a;
- html request to / -> the server answer with index.html file;
- request to / -> the server answer with route "/" with Controller b

There is a way to do that in Play?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply look at your routes file under conf. It defines the routes in your web application. You can specify the type of route, the URL pattern and which controller/method will handle it. For example,

```
GET    /                                 controllers.Dashboard.view()
GET    /dashboard/viewdata/:service      controllers.Dashboard.viewData(service: String)
GET    /dashboard/hourlydemand           controllers.Dashboard.hourlyDemandData
GET    /customerservice/meterinfo/daily  controllers.customerService.MeterReports.daily
```

In the second route above, service is grabbed from the URL as a string and passed to the viewData() method of the Dashboard controller.

See also here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting

If you need to handle a single controller request route with different results, then you can do something like the following:

```
public Result list() {
    List<Item> items = Item.find.all();
    if (request().accepts("text/html")) {
        return ok(views.html.Application.list.render(items));
    } else {
        return ok(Json.toJson(items));
    }
}
```

Taken from: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaContentNegotiation

Comment: I understood how to root stuff, but what I need is something like:

`GET *  controllers.Home.requestAcceptHTML()` and in the controller, if in the request header has `Accept  text/html` I answer with the index file, OR i just use the other routes I have in Play

Comment: It would be two separate routes for this, I think. One that addresses the .html route and the other for the JSON route. Or you could handle it in the controller itself and pass back the appropriate type of response based on the request. E.g. if you ask for /path/index.html, then you handle that route pattern to return html. If it simply goes to /path, then you can perhaps return JSON. Up to you how you choose to code your routes :)

Comment: @ManoDestra You can use content negotiation for this. Separate routes aren't necessary.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that above.

Comment: Actually, BEFORE you mentioned it, if you had read my full comment: "Or you could handle it in the controller itself and pass back the appropriate type of response based on the request.". I merely edited my answer above to include a reference to it.

Comment: @Kris you gave your answer 1 hour ago and yet I made my comment above 3 hours ago. Your math is exceedingly off. `It would be two separate routes for this, I think. One that addresses the .html route and the other for the JSON route. Or you could handle it in the controller itself and pass back the appropriate type of response based on the request. E.g. if you ask for /path/index.html, then you handle that route pattern to return html. If it simply goes to /path, then you can perhaps return JSON. Up to you how you choose to code your routes :) ` Your comment merely echoed this precisely.

Comment: Everyone can look in the history of your edits. Have fun. I'm out.

Comment: My comment wasn't edited. My answer WAS, to reflect the nature of my comment. And I decided to amend my answer after you commented, as I thought it worthwhile to include an example based on what I said in my comment. My comment prior to yours (unedited) reflected exactly what you stated after it and I've posted it twice now to highlight that fact. Sheesh!